# How to call a web service inside another webservice

Tags: java, web-services, wso2, apache-axis

I need to consume a secure webservice deployed in WSO2 AS from another web service develop in axis2 and deployed in apache tomcat.
I create a java project to test the secure webservice client and I work OK.
But when I move the client code inside the axis2 service I cannot access to some resources like in this cases:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "keys\\store.jks");
```

in this case I have the keys folder in the root of the wb services

```
    sc.engageModule("rampart");
```

and in this case I leave the code idem

Any idea about this?

Comment: Does tomcat hosting the consumer webservice have another keystore file. Similar problem happended to me when i tried to set trustore as system property while the server(WSO2 AS) itself has a keystore. In that case they conflict with eachother. Maybe you are hitting a similar problem?

Comment: No, my problem is related to the fact that I put my keys folder inside the webservice, and I want to know the path to that folder from a class inside this webservice because  keys\\store.jks don´t work.

Comment: So as i understand your keystore file is inside your .aar as a resource file and you want to load it while doing ssl connection am i correct?

Comment: yes correcto, in a java project I create a client for this webservice and I need to use the jks for the secure conection and some axis2 modules like rampart for creating the soapmessage with the right headers....so when I move the code inside another webservice I put this folder in the resource folder and maven put them at the root of the webservice.aar....now if I open the .aar file I see the keys folder and a repo folder that contain my rampart module. but I don´t know the path to this resources

Answer (score 0):

Well getting a resource path from an archieve file whether it is a jar ,war or aar is a tedious problem. There are two options two choose from:

1- Since client application runs on a servers put jks file somewhere on the server path, its path retrieved dynamically via property. (Either system property, servers context etc.) 
2- A customSSLFactory handling loading keystore from resources.

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104512/setting-grizzlys-keystore-to-use-a-jks-in-a-jar) mentions such solution, which i used it too to connect to server via SSL from a web service without touching system properties.